# Paperclip Gem - How to get the hash of the generated filename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using the Paperclip gem and saving three copies of each of my images.  My paths look something like this:

"img/thumb/f80386a363e077dc08fb80a5c8908c1d78b7.png"

**How can I extract only the hash part of this path from the Paperclip attached file object?**

Obviously I could parse the hash out of this, but loading times are extremely important for my application, and I would prefer to quickly extract only the hash for each image.  All files are stored as jpg, so this can also be appended on the client.  I poked around the Paperclip object, but could not find a way to access the hash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With an instance of an 'Image' model named 'image', which has an attachment named 'attachment', this can be done with:

```
image.attachment.hash_key
```

You can see the documentation of the image assets [here](http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Attachment#path-instance_method).